# Intermittent connection drops using MS Graph API for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, serverxmlhttp

Since 06.02.2020 our interface with a clients Sharepoint (using MSGraph API) has been experiencing intermittent connection drops when trying to download a file using [@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#instance-attributes).

Our application makes a HTTP GET request (using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0) to the provided url. Then after a certain amount of time an error gets thrown with the description "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally". No status code, no response content.

This also occurs using any browser (by copying the downloadUrl to the address bar and hitting enter). Chrome, with a file download (lets say the url points to a .jpg file), will say "Failed - Network error".

The error can be replicated (IF it is a global problem) using Curl with this batch script.

```
@echo off

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%1) DO (
    echo.
    echo Attempt: %%A%

    rem Writing output into a file, extension is not really important.
    curl --output "output.jpg" %2
)
```

Which can be called like `test.bat <no of tries> "<@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl>"`. Added a log [here](https://pastebin.com/rSkS6e5n), attempts 13, 15 and 18 get the error.

I'm not really sure what could be happening here. I've researched the error message and basically what happens is that the socket gets just dropped unexpectedly. I was thinking maybe there's a quota we are hitting with our requests, but in these cases MSGraph returns a proper error message and there is no background application bombarding MSGraph using these links. The links are used to show a pdf preview in the browser window for example.

Any ideas what could be wrong or where I could go for help?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you update your question to include a `downloadUrl` that you saw this issue with, and the timestamp (in UTC) when it failed? Feel free to remove the `tempauth` query string parameter from the URL so that it will not function.

Comment: @Brad I don't want to post the full url because it contains the companies name. Maybe the unique id is sufficient:
`2020-02-25T07:33:48Z https://<company_name>.sharepoint.com/sites/<folder_name>/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=8d7a6206-f516-4768-97a7-fd011b9a8b36&Translate=false&tempauth=<temp_auth_key_removed>&ApiVersion=2.0`

Comment: That's perfectly reasonable - The unique id and the time stamp will most likely be enough to let us find what we're looking for

Comment: We found the information for that request, and it looks like the service sent 62437 bytes in ~80ms and completed with a 200 OK. Can you confirm that this was one of the failure cases?

Comment: @Brad Can confirm. The Curl tests I conducted showed the same behaviour, a portion of the file got downloaded and then the download speed fell to 0 and after a few moments an error gets thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We believe we tracked down the root cause of this issue - can all of those who were observing it let us know if things look better?

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 2):

Apologize for using the answer field but I only have 35 reputation so I could not add a comment and I want to add our experience in case this is affecting others.

We are experiencing the same issue which started around the same date as the OP mentions.  We have been using the same code for about 2 and a half years and it has never skipped a beat, but now users are having an issue when they download reports.  These reports download multiple pdfs via the MSGraph API and then combine them into a single pdf.  What I have noticed is if there are only a few pdf files in a particular report, it is fine. If I debug the session and iterate through the files at a slower pace (ie I count to 3 after each one) it is fine.  Also the users can sometimes get around it by trying again, and maybe of the 4th or 5th try it might work.

Like the OP I thought we were hitting a quota but the error is "an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" and not "HTTP status code 429 (Too many requests)".

Comment: @ejx are you noticing when it fails it takes quite some time to return the error?  The pdf's we are fetching via the API are tiny, less than 100K mostly, so usually it fetches them in ~500ms, but when it encounters the error it will take ~10 seconds to return the error. I am working around this error but catching it then retrying the fetch one last time so far works.  It must be some sort of throttling MS has added and not sending the correct error code.

Comment: Exactly! The logging I did with Curl confirms what you said and we experience a delay on our application as well before the error is thrown. Also on Curl I noticed the download speed started to drop until it hit 0 and then after a few seconds the error is thrown. It would be nice to get someone from MS to comment on this issue.

Comment: When this happens, I'd be curious to know what the value of the `Content-Length` header is, and how many bytes your applications retrieve before things seem to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint usually return a proper error code 429 or 503 when it is throttling. Dropping socket usually hits a code path that has some issues. You may consider filing a support ticket. There is a possibility that someone will be able to take a look at the specific issue. I have tried to reproduce doing the repeated download. But I am not able to. So the error may reproduce with specific condition.